# ([firebase_auth/unknown] null) when Sign In with Apple on android Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, apple-sign-in

I've implemented Apple sign in for my app using `sign_in_with_apple: ^4.3.0` plugin and on iOS it all works as expected, but on Android signInWithCredential throws `[firebase_auth/unknown] null` error.

I created a `ServiceID` and I added my firebase project url in `Domains and Subdomains` and the auth handler from Firebase console in `Return URLs`. This was working fine with iOS but on Android I was getting `Unable to process request due to missing initial state.`  error.
Searching for the error I found to that Firebase doesn't work well with it (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4256) and I saw that others set a Cloud Function for it([How to write Firebase Functions for Sign in with Apple on Flutter Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675577/how-to-write-firebase-functions-for-sign-in-with-apple-on-flutter-android)). So I set up an end point on my Node.js server run-in on AKS and added the server domain in `Domains and Subdomains` and end point url in `Return URLs` of the ServiceID.
[image]

The Apple sign in flow and pop up are correct. I receive the authorised Apple credentials but one difference I see is that the `userIdentifier` is null while on iOS is not, and on Android `authorizationCode` parameter is missing completely.

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> authorizeAppleIdCredentials() async {
    final rawNonce = _generateNonce();
    final nonce = _sha256ofString(rawNonce);

    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(
        'https://xxx.xxxxx.cloudapp.azure.com/server/api/apple_callback'
        // 'https://xxxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler' // still getting the Unable to process request due to missing initial state error.
        );
    WebAuthenticationOptions webOptions =
        WebAuthenticationOptions(clientId: 'xxxx', redirectUri: uri);

    /// Request credential for the currently signed in Apple account.
    final AuthorizationCredentialAppleID appleIdCredential =
        await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      webAuthenticationOptions: webOptions,
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      nonce: nonce,
    ).catchError((e) {
      print(
          'UserRepository.authorizeAppleIDCredentials() SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential error: $e');
    });

    Map<String, dynamic> authorizedAppleCredential = {
      'appleIdCredential': {
        'email': appleIdCredential.email,
        'familyName': appleIdCredential.familyName,
        'givenName': appleIdCredential.givenName,
        'userIdentifier': appleIdCredential.userIdentifier,
        'identityToken': appleIdCredential.identityToken,
        'authorizationCode': appleIdCredential.authorizationCode,
        'state': appleIdCredential.state
      },
      'rawNonce': rawNonce
    };
    dev.log(
        'UserRepository.authorizeAppleIDCredentials() SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential is $appleIdCredential\n'
        'authorizedAppleCredential is $authorizedAppleCredential');
    return authorizedAppleCredential;
  }
```

on Android

```
authorizedAppleCredential is {appleIdCredential: {email: myMAil@gmail.com, familyName: surname, givenName: vincenzo, userIdentifier: null, identityToken: some token, state: null}, rawNonce: jsH8DDAoURn1Vf8z.hvxM_sAqxu.PGGP}
```

on iOS

```
authorizeAppleIdCredentials is: {appleIdCredential: {email: myMaili@gmail.com, familyName: surname, givenName: vincenzo, userIdentifier: xxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxx, identityToken: some token, authorizationCode: some auth code, state: null}, rawNonce: BmhreGGUY.3E-Ni0_9yi3yJ_0v6bZ0Me}
```

I'm not sure if that is the problem, but for creating the OAuth credentials is not used, `identityToken` is used and that is present:

```
Future<OAuthCredential> createAppleOauthCredential(
      {required Map<String, dynamic> authorizedAppleCredential,
      required String rawNonce}) async {
    // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
    print(
        'UserRepository.createAppleOauthCredentials apple idToken is ${authorizedAppleCredential['appleIdCredential']['identityToken']}'); //correct
    print(
        'UserRepository.createAppleOauthCredentials rawNonce is ${authorizedAppleCredential['rawNonce']}'); // correct

    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: authorizedAppleCredential['appleIdCredential']['identityToken'],
      rawNonce: rawNonce,
    );
    return oauthCredential;
  }
```

and the prints I get from it are the same both on iOS and Android.

```
AuthCredential(providerId: apple.com, signInMethod: oauth, token: null, accessToken: null)
```

Now using those OAuth credentials I can sign in into firebase auth without problems on iOS but not on Android.

```
Future<User?> signInWithCredential(
      {required AuthCredential oauthCredential}) async {
    // Future<User?> signInWithCredential({required OAuthCredential oauthCredential}) async {
    // Sign in the user with Firebase. If the nonce we generated earlier does
    // not match the nonce in `appleCredential.identityToken`, sign in will fail.
    UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
        .signInWithCredential(oauthCredential)
        .catchError((e) {
      print('_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential) error: $e');
    });
    dev.log(
        'UserRepository.signInWithCredential() user is: ${userCredential.user}');

    return userCredential.user;
  }
```

and the print is `_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(oauthCredential) error: [firebase_auth/unknown] null`.

This is the endpoint

```
exports.callback = async (req, res) => {
  const package_name = 'xxxxx';
    const redirect = `intent://callback?${new URLSearchParams(
      req.body
    ).toString()}#Intent;package=${package_name};scheme=signinwithapple;end`;

    console.log('apple callback req is: ', req);
    console.log(`Redirecting to ${redirect}`);

    res.redirect(307, redirect);

};
```

And this is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxxxx"
    >

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <queries>
        <!--UrlLauncher If your app opens https URLs -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="xxx"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification" />

<!--        <meta-data-->
<!--            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"-->
<!--            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />-->


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>


            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="flutterstripe" android:host="safepay" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Set up the Sign in with Apple activity, such that it's callable from the browser-redirect -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.aboutyou.dart_packages.sign_in_with_apple.SignInWithAppleCallback"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="signinwithapple" />
                <data android:path="/callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<!--        <receiver android:name="cox-->
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <!-- Specify that the launch screen should continue being displayed -->
        <!-- until Flutter renders its first frame. -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

        <!-- Theme to apply as soon as Flutter begins rendering frames -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2"
            />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that I wasn't using the `authorizationCode` from the `AuthorizationCredentialAppleID` in `OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential` `accessToken` and once added it all works as expected, so the corrected method is:

```
Future<OAuthCredential> createAppleOauthCredential(
      {required Map<String, dynamic> authorizedAppleCredential,
      required String rawNonce}) async {
    // Create an `OAuthCredential` from the credential returned by Apple.
    log('UserRepository.createAppleOauthCredentials apple idToken is ${authorizedAppleCredential['appleIdCredential']['identityToken']}');
    log('UserRepository.createAppleOauthCredentials rawNonce is ${authorizedAppleCredential['rawNonce']}');
    final oauthCredential = OAuthProvider("apple.com").credential(
      idToken: authorizedAppleCredential['appleIdCredential']['identityToken'],
      accessToken: authorizedAppleCredential['appleIdCredential']
          ['authorizationCode'], // new
      rawNonce: rawNonce,
    );
    return oauthCredential;
  }
```